# accessing master page session in child pages

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, master-pages, sql-sessions

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

```
    lblSTuName.Text = "Welcome! " + Session("StuID")
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        con.Open()
    End If
    cmd = New OleDbCommand
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "select [Image] from tblStudent where Uname='" + Session("StuID") + "'"
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If dr.Read() Then
        stuImage.ImageUrl = dr("Image")
    Else
        stuImage.ImageUrl = Nothing
    End If
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

i have this code in student.master page

and then i want the session("StuID") to use in chlid page also....i have written the following code in the child page student.aspx-

If Not IsPostBack Then

```
        Dim stname As Label = TryCast(Master.FindControl("lblSTuName"), Label)
        stuN = stname.Text
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Open()
        End If
        cmd = New OleDbCommand
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "select [RollNo],[CourceName] from tblStudent where StuName='" + stuN + "'"
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If dr.Read() Then
            MsgBox("read complete")

        Else
            MsgBox("not success!")
        End If
    End If
```

but i am not able to use session here in the child page using this code.Can i get any help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only one session object for each user. You can access this data from any page. Try to use student name directly from the session. You don't need any master page for this

```
       .....
       Dim stuN =  Session("StuID");
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Open()
        End If
        cmd = New OleDbCommand
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "select [RollNo],[CourceName] from tblStudent where StuName='" + stuN + "'"
       // or better to try
      cmd.CommandText = "select [RollNo],[CourceName] from tblStudent where Uname='" + stuN + "'"
       ......
```

Comment: Hyi,,,,,now i am getting error again .The messagebox with message "not success" is getting displayed. I have added following lines of code-

Comment: Hyi,,,,,now i am getting error again .The message box with message "not success" is getting displayed. I have added following lines of code-      
            Dim stuN As String = Session("StuID")

Comment: Did you try "select [RollNo],[CourceName] from tblStudent where Uname='" + stuN + "'"